# Removing Window from Matplotlib 3d Scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have the axes on my 3d graph labeled, but there is still this generic 2d frame around my 3d projection that I cant get rid of.

How do I remove the x and y [0, 1] axes around the outside of my 3d graph?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg="None")
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X[:, 1], X[:, 0], X[:, 2], c=labels, alpha=0.4)

ax.set_xlabel('Pressure Integral', fontsize=12, color='blue', rotation=150)
ax.set_ylabel('Total Gallons', fontsize=12, color='blue')
ax.set_zlabel('Duration (seconds)', fontsize=12, color='blue', rotation=60)
ax.yaxis._axinfo['label']['space_factor'] = 3.0
```

[image]

Comment: The frame is there because you put it there with your code. Without knowing the code that produces this plot, that's all once can say. Please read and understand [mcve]. Else this becomes the great guessing game.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I absolutely did not put it there, see code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "absolutely" did put the line

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg="None")
```

in your code. Remove this line, to get rid of the axes that is produced by it.